# How do I include an IF statement in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

**MySQL**

table1:

```
+----+--------+---------+------+
| id | itemid |   type  | name |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 1  |   1    | product |  t   |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 2  |   2    | product |  t   |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 3  |   3    | service |  t   |
+----+--------+---------+------+
```

table2:

```
+--------+---------+
| itemid | display |
+--------+---------+
|   1    |    1    |
+--------+---------+
```

**PHP**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%t' ....");
```

I want to modify the query above and also test:

If `type = product` then `itemid` should not be included in `table2` where `display = 1`.

**Further Explanation:**

So, I want to see whether or not the row in `table1` that matches `t` is a product.

If it **is not** a product (i.e. service), just go ahead and **display it**.

If it **is** a product, I want to further check whether or not its `itemid` is included in `table2`

If it **is included**, then **don't display it.**

If it **is not included**, then **display it.**

Sorry, I don't know how else to explain it. :/

Comment: i see no field called `product`....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would be necessary to add any rows. But I added them now ;)

Comment: You should also add the whole query, obviously you are omitting the join, or some other part, which would be connected to `table2`, otherwise your query would never return anything from it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'should not be included in table2' ?

Comment: I could do `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 AND itemid NOT IN (SELECT itemid FROM table2 WHERE display = 1)` but then I'm obviously forgetting to test whether or not `type = product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to exclude rows whose type = 'product':

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid 
AND t1.id = '1' 
AND t1.type <> 'product'
```

(If that's not what you want, IMHO some further explanation is necessary)

UPDATE: to exclude all whose type = 'product' having a matching row in table2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.id = '1' 
AND (t1.type <> 'product' OR NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT NULL from table2 t2 
 WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid )
```

Comment: What I want to do should look something like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 AND IF(type = product, itemid NOT IN (SELECT itemid FROM table2 WHERE display = 1)` ...not sure if it's possible to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what exactly you are looking for, but I think you can accomplish your goal by building a select statement for each case of your IF statement, then unioning the results. This may not be *exactly* what you're looking for (like I said, I'm a little confused) but I bet your solution will at least look close to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
AND type <> 'product'
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid
AND t1.id =1
AND type = product
and t2.display <> 1
```